# Can not compare std::unorded_set with custom KeyEqual

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

The following program does not compile. But If I do not comment out `operator==`, it compiles. Why `operator==` is still needed when I already provide `FooEqual`

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Foo {
};

struct FooHasher {
  size_t operator()(const Foo&) const {
    return 1;
  }
};

struct FooEqual {
  bool operator()(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) const {
    return true;
  }
};

// bool operator==(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
//   return true;
// }

int main() {
  std::unordered_set<Foo, FooHasher, FooEqual> s1;
  std::unordered_set<Foo, FooHasher, FooEqual> s2;
  (void)(s1 == s2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Must be a bug in the implementation ... unless the spec says that `KeqEqual` is only used for insertion/lookup and that `std::unordered_set::operator==` checks whether two sets are equal based on whether the individual elements compare equal? Might need a C++ language lawyer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"23.2.5 Unordered associative containers" states:

> Two unordered containers a and b compare equal if a.size() == b.size()
>   and, for every equivalent=key group [Ea1,Ea2) obtained from
>   a.equal_range(Ea1), there exists an equivalent-key group [Eb1,Eb2)
>   obtained from b.equal_range(Ea1), such that distance(Ea1, Ea2) ==
>   distance(Eb1, Eb2) and is_permutation(Ea1, Ea2, Eb1) returns true.

Stripping this down, it all comes down to the equality of unordered containers being defined in terms of `std::is_permutation()`.

The important part is that this references the three argument form of `std::is_permutation`(), and not the four argument form!

In other words, the whole house of cards ends up being reduced to the default `operator==`, for the contents of the unordered container, rather than the container's official comparison function.

That's my read on this.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/operator_cmp you do in fact need the `operator==` for comparison (I don't have access to the standard right now - I'll try to update with the specific quote sometime tomorrow):

> The behavior is undefined if Key is not EqualityComparable.
>
> The behavior is also undefined if Hash and KeyEqual do not have the
>   same behavior on lhs and rhs or if the equality comparison operator
>   for Key is not a refinement of the partition into equivalent-key
>   groups introduced by KeyEqual (that is, if two keys that compare equal
>   fall into different partitions)