# Why is the KeyEqual of std::unordered_map not used by its operator==?

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map, language-design

In the following code, I have defined template arguments `Hash` and `KeyEqual` for `unordered_map`. I expect the output to be `1 1 1 1` but it is actually `1 1 0 1`. Why does this happen? Is it because `std::equal_to<Base*>` is not used in comparing maps with `==`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Base {
public:
    int x;
    Base(int _x) : x(_x) {}

    bool operator==(const Base& another) const {
        return x == another.x;
    }
    size_t hash() const {return x;}
};

template <>
struct std::hash<Base> {
    size_t operator()(const Base& r) const {
        return r.hash();
    }
};

template <>
struct std::hash<Base*> {
    size_t operator()(const Base *r) const {
        return r->hash();
    }
};

template <>
struct std::equal_to<Base*> {
    bool operator()(const Base *r1, const Base *r2) const {
        return (*r1) == (*r2);
    }
};

int main(int, char**){
    Base b1(1);
    Base b2(2);
    Base bb1(1);
    Base bb2(2);
    cout << (b1 == bb1) << endl;

    std::unordered_map<Base, int> map1;
    map1.emplace(b1, 1);
    map1.emplace(b2, 2);
    std::unordered_map<Base, int> map2;
    map2.emplace(bb1, 1);
    map2.emplace(bb2, 2);
    cout << (map1 == map2) << endl;

    std::unordered_map<Base*, int, std::hash<Base*>, std::equal_to<Base*>> map11;
    map11.emplace(&b1, 1);
    map11.emplace(&b2, 2);
    std::unordered_map<Base*, int, std::hash<Base*>, std::equal_to<Base*>> map22;
    map22.emplace(&bb1, 1);
    map22.emplace(&bb2, 2);
    cout << (map11 == map22) << endl;

    std::unordered_map<Base*, int, std::hash<Base*>, std::equal_to<Base*>> map33;
    map33.emplace(&b1, 1);
    map33.emplace(&b2, 2);
    cout << (map11 == map33) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `operator==` bypasses they `KeyEqual` for `std::unordered_map`

Contrary to intuition, the `==` operator for `std::unordered_map` does not care about `std::hash` or about `std::key_equal`; it relies on the built-in `==` operator for your type.

> Two unordered containers a and b compare equal if `a.size() == b.size()` and, for every equivalent-key group `[Ea1, Ea2)` obtained from `a.equal_range(Ea1)`, there exists an equivalent-key group `[Eb1, Eb2)` obtained from `b.equal_range(Ea1)`, such that `is_permutation(Ea1, Ea2, Eb1, Eb2)` returns `true`.

- [[unord.req.general] p242](https://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req.general#242)

Notice how the ranges which are tested for equality (in your case, they will simply contain one pointer each) do not use they `KeyEqual` provided to the container. It is defined in terms of `is_permutation` with no `KeyEqual`, which simply uses the built-in `==` operator.

#### What is the rationale for this?!

Containers in general don't consider the `KeyEqual`, `Less` (in the case of `std::set`), etc. which you provide to them. All comparison operators are simply forwarded to the contained elements, and this design is consistent, even though it's counter-intuitive.

For two `std::unordered_map`s with two (stateful) `KeyEqual`s, there is another motivation:

> In general, computing permutations is a quadratic operation. However, given two unordered
> containers that use the same hash and key-equivalence functions, the elements will be partitioned into
> key-equivalence groups that make comparison much more efficient.

- [N2986: Equality Comparison for Unordered Containers](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2986.pdf)

---

*See also [Can not compare std::unorded_set with custom KeyEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36167764/5740428)*

Comment: I customized the comparison by comparing the sizes of the maps and comparing the key-value pairs, and this works fine.

Comment: It seems like in this example, the equality comparison function IS a refinement of the partition generated by KeyEqual.  That is `a == b` implies `KeyEqual(a, b)` for all possible keys.

Comment: @ChrisDodd you're right, so it's well-defined. It's just well-defined to have a surprising result.